# REST WEB API: How to make Content-Type header optional?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have Web API and would like to make the content type optional.

Currently if I ignored content-Type header while calling REST (POST) Method it throws error.

This is how I defined route in Web API -

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "myMethodPost",
   routeTemplate: "api/{id}/Settings/{settings}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Settings", action = "updateSettings" },
   constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
);
```

while calling this method -

```
api/1/Settings/testSettings
method = "Post"
```

it throws error. but when added following -

```
apiRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
```

it is working fine.

Now, how to make Content-Type header optional?

Comment: why do you want to make it optional? if a request has body and not content-type header, then Web API cannot figure out which formatter to choose for deserializing the request body...what is your exact scenario?

Comment: @KiranChalla, yes you are right....I am having custom type in the parameter list, and it is failing to bind the parameter just because of absence of ContentType.

Comment: An entity without a content type is not an entity, it's just a bunch or random 1s and 0s that mean nothing. Why not fix the bug where the client isn't sending a content type, rather than introduce a bug where the server will allow that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a messagehandler on the server that will set the Content-Type to 'application/json' if it is missing and there is a non-zero length body.  That way the client doesn't have to send it.

Comment: I added messagehandler and wrote this line - request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); but still the custom type parameter is empty

Comment: well I got it, I added following in the messagehandler - 
"request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");"

Comment: Does anyone have example code showing how to fix this issue in asp.net Core 2.2? I don't want Content-Type to be required for Rest API. It already caused some grief for one of my API consumers.